# How can I send a `HttpRequestMessage` from Client-side Blazor Wasm to Server-side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have the ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor WebAssembly project with the project structure of Client,Server and Shared.
I want to build a resolver class which will receive a `HttpRequestMessage` from a controller. I want to have the usage of multiple databases in runtime. Therefore I am building this resolver which will instantiate the following DbContext like this:

my `startup.cs` :

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            //****** CHANGE DBCONTEXT WHEN HTTPRESPONSEMESSSAGE IS "TEST" HERE ******//
            services
                .AddDbContext<SQLServerDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(_configuration["ConnectionStrings:SQLServerConnection"]))
                .AddDbContext<SQLiteTestDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlite(_configuration["ConnectionStrings:SQLiteTestConnection"]))
                .AddScoped<DbContextResolver>()
                .AddScoped<IDbContext>(p =>
                {
                    var resolver = p.GetRequiredService<DbContextResolver>();
                    if (!resolver.IsTest)
                    {
                        return p.GetRequiredService<SQLiteTestDbContext>();  // <--- use this DbContext when DbContextResolver.IsTest = true.
                    }
                    return p.GetRequiredService<SQLServerDbContext>();   // <--- use this DbContext when DbContextResolver.IsTest = false.
                });
            ...
         }
```

My DbContextResolver class has only one public porperty: `public bool IsTest { get; set; }`
I also have built this middleware-function which will receive the `HttpRequestMessage`and reference back to the DbContext initialization.

```cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                var resolver = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<DbContextResolver>();
                resolver.IsTest = context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("test"); // <--- Getting the HttpResponseMessage and setting therefore the resolver property.
                return next();
            });
            ... 
        }
```

All code here is in the Server-Side Application.
I'm still quite new to ASP.NET Core and Blazor WebAssembly and don't know how to receive a message from the Client-Side Application.

Comment: As I understand it the client side talks to the server side via SignalR. In this respect it's no different whether you use fully server-hosted Blazor or use the web assembly client-side hosting. I haven't used it yet but been reading about it, it seemed to me that you didn't need to worry directly about the client/server model, just build your app according to the patterns the framework provides. It's unclear why you want to send a HTTP request (at least I think that's what you want). You should be able to use the existing SignalR connection between client and server to communicate

Comment: @ADyson In Blazor Webasm I have got 3 components.These are "Client","Server" and "Shared". Now the Client application has no reference to the Server and therefore I need to send HttpClients to affect any of these changes. In my usecase the user should be able to switch the database. I built the Resolver class for this which get set by the HttpRequestMessage from the Client, when as example a button gets clicked in the UI the DbContext for SQLite will be instantiated. But my problem is how to send the Request to the server side. In Debug the server is running and is building up the client also.

Comment: Are you sure you've set everything up correctly? Take a look at the Blazor intro tutorial here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio as you can see, all you do is define a page and define some events which occur when the user does something, e.g click a button. You don't need to explicitly do anything about connections. You can even use the exact same code whether you're using server-side Blazor or webassembly Blazor.The runtime takes care of sending messages between client and server, it's all abstracted away by the event model

Comment: You might also want to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.1 to further understand the architecture.